# iOS Geofencing not calling 'didEnterRegion' ,didExitRegion, 'didStartMonitoringForRegion'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, geofencing

iOS Geofencing not calling `didEnterRegion` , `didExitRegion` and `didStartMonitoringForRegion` in objective c.

I want to implement a single view application, where I use Google maps SDK in cocoa pods.

I have included appropriate keys in info.plist like this

```
 <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Location is required for geofence</string>
 <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Location is required for geofence</string>
```

Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
double Lat=22.569643; 
double Lon=88.432058; 
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:Lat longitude:Lon zoom:14];
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
self.view=_mapView;
_mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Lat, Lon) radius:52];
circ.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
circ.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
circ.strokeWidth = 1;
circ.map = _mapView;
 CLCircularRegion *cir=[[CLCircularRegion alloc]initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Lat, Lon) radius:52 identifier:@"hi"];
locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:cir];
cir.notifyOnEntry = YES;
cir.notifyOnExit = YES;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Are you running your code on the simulator?

Comment: no..it's run  on Iphone

Answer (score 0):

Apple says (in the [Location & Maps PG](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW11)) that the minimum distance for regions should be assumed to be 200m.

> The specific threshold distances are determined by the hardware and the location technologies that are currently available. For example, if Wi-Fi is disabled, region monitoring is significantly less accurate. However, for testing purposes, you can assume that the minimum distance is approximately 200 meters.

I also faced a similar problem with geofencing. It works well when you increase the radius to 100m. If you want to monitor a region with a smaller radius, you should listen for location updates and check if the location is present in the region around the point.